# how to create endpoint for downloading pdf files?

Tags: hooks, endpoints

I would like the logged-in user to be able to download the PDF file, but not to see the real path to the file.  Additionally, in this PDF file, I enter information about the user name and date of download.

I created a new endpoint "download" to make the download address look like this: my-website.com/post-name/download/attached-id

```
function my_custom_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'download', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}  
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_endpoint' );
```

but I don't know what the hook is to not load the page after calling this endpoint but to call my function and return the PDF file to the user.

Comment: Do not forget to refresh your permalinks: manually (Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes) or programatically (by `flush_rewrite_rules()`). If you choose function, use it carefully - [it's heavy function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/)

Answer (score 0):

A good action to hook in would be [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/). There you can query for your endpoint like this:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    global $wp_query;
    
    // Not your endpoint and not a page/post, we do nothing.
    if (!isset( $wp_query->query_vars['download']) || ! is_singular()) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Here goes your magic!
    […]
    
    // And probably a good idea to exit if you serve files.
    exit;
});
```

There's also a [great tutorial about endpoints](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) on *Make WordPress*.